# How to use While with out using Datagridview in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I'm having trouble with this since I'm quite new with vb, the problem I'm having is that the data isn't actually looping, it only displays a single data.

index.aspx

```
<div class="row ">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-12 ">
                <% 
                
                %>
                <div class="panel panel-default ">
                    <div class="panel-body bg-primary bg-radius">
                        <div class="row bg-white">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="content" style=" font-size:18px;">
                                    <div class="control-label">
                                        <p><b>Date:</b> <asp:Label ID="lblDateWhen" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></p>
                                        <p><b>Time and Duration:</b> <asp:Label ID="lblTime1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> - <asp:Label ID="lblTime2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> (<asp:Label ID="lblDuration" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> hrs)</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-label">
                                        <p><b>Affected Areas:</b> <asp:Label ID="lblAreas" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></p>
                                        <p><b>Reason: </b><asp:Label ID="lblReason" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

index.aspx.vb

```
Public Sub DisplayInterruption()
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * from table where date_when >=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP order by date_when asc", con)
    Dim rd As SqlDataReader
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While rd.Read()
    If rd.HasRows = False Then
    lblDateWhen.Text = "No post."
    lblAreas.Visible = False
    ion.Text = False
    lblReason.Text = False
    lblTime1.Visible = False
    lblTime2.Visible = False
    Else
    Dim dt1 As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(rd.Item("time_start").ToString(), "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Dim dt2 As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(rd.Item("time_end").ToString(), "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    
    Dim duration As TimeSpan = dt2 - dt1

    lblDateWhen.Text = Format(rd.Item("date_when"), "MMMM d, yyyy")
    blTime1.Text = dt1.ToShortTimeString()
    blTime2.Text = dt2.ToShortTimeString()
    lblDuration.Text = duration.TotalHours
    lblAreas.Text = rd.Item("areas").ToString()
    lblReason.Text = rd.Item("activities").ToString()
    End If
    End While
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

I also tried using For Each but it didn't work

Comment: How could you possibly show more than one record in one set of controls? If you have one `Label` and you keep setting its `Text` property over and over, what makes you think that you'd see anything but the last value you put into it? Maybe you should be using a `GridView`, which is the most direct equivalent to a `DataGridView` in Web Forms.

Comment: Never thought of that, Thanks!

Comment: Use indentation in all your VB code.  It makes reading code much easier.

Comment: @SezMe Sorry about that, I'm using indentations with all my VB Codes after I got this one to work. It really is annoying to look at when it doesn't have any indentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare you database objects in the method where they are used so they can be closed and disposed. Using...End Using blocks will handle this for you even if there is an error.

```
Protected Sub DisplayInterruption()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * from interruptions where date_when >=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP order by date_when asc", con)
        con.Open()
        Using rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dt.Load(rd)
        End Using
    End Using
    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        lblDateWhen.Text = "No scheduled interruptions posted."
        lblAreas.Visible = False
        ion.Text = False
        lblReason.Text = False
        lblTime1.Visible = False
        lblTime2.Visible = False
    Else
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." because of the connection string

Comment: That is not normally what that error means. Did you insert your connection string?

Comment: there was a problem with my Web.config, was lucky I have another copy of it. Btw thanks for this!